# LinkedList, leetcode #83, condition is always met

Tags: java, linked-list

Why this code not working? if (head != head.next) and (head.val != head.next.val) work in 100% of cases. But I found in the answers a code with the same condition that works for a person. Please help me find the error.

LeetCode: https://leetcode.com/problems/remove-duplicates-from-sorted-list/description/

```
/**
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {

        ListNode trueResult = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode result = trueResult;

        while (head != null) {
                
                if (head != head.next) {
                    result.next = head;
                    head = head.next;
                }

                result = result.next;
        }

        return trueResult.next;
    }
}
```

Result: `head = [1,1,2,3,3] output = [1,1,2,3,3] expected = [1,2,3]`

This code work. Why?

```
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * public class ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode next;
 *     ListNode() {}
 *     ListNode(int val) { this.val = val; }
 *     ListNode(int val, ListNode next) { this.val = val; this.next = next; }
 * }
 */
class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
        
        ListNode temp = head;

        while( temp != null && temp.next != null ){

            if( temp.val == temp.next.val ){
                temp.next = temp.next.next;
            }
            else{
                temp = temp.next;
            }

        }

        return head;

    }
}
```

if (head != head.next) and if (head.val != head.next.val) work to 100% cases. All time i take a bad result.

im try to use head.val != head.next.val, but its not work :(

Comment: I believe that you were supposed to work with duplicate **values**. Your code makes no use of the `val` item at all.

Comment: teapot418, I wrote that the value also does not work. tried this and that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems in your code.

1. References comparison

```
if (head != head.next)
```

This condition is always `true` as you compare `references`. You should compare `ListNode#val` instead.

**a.** replace the check with `head.val != head.next.val`. Take care of `null` check for `head.next`

**b.** if `head.next` is null you should always fall into the `if` statement as this is the last element

2. You always advance `result` and do not advance `head`

Even if you met duplicate you advance results which does not make sense. If we found a duplicate we should not advance `result` as we did not modify the list.

**a.** Instead of advancing result you need to advance `head` every iteration, i.e. mode `head = head.next` out of `if` statement

**b.** You need to advance result only when there is no duplicates, i.e. move `result` advancing into `if` statement

I applied all the highlights to your code, you can see it below:

```
class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {

        ListNode trueResult = new ListNode(-1);
        ListNode result = trueResult;

        while (head != null) {
                
                if (head.next == null || (head.next != null && head.val != head.next.val)) {
                    result.next = head;
                    result = result.next;
                }

                head = head.next;
        }

        return trueResult.next;
    }
}
```

Happy coding!

Comment: yes, im use to "head.next.val" and it is work, haha. thx so much and im so sorry. have a good day!

Comment: No worries! This is the only way of learning literally anything - through making mistakes.

Answer (score -2):

They seem to want this (like):

```java
class Solution {
    public ListNode deleteDuplicates(ListNode head) {
        ListNode cur = head; // "cursor" head to tail
        while (cur != null) {
            ListNode del = cur.next; // cursor over "deletion candidates"
            while (del != null && del.val <= cur.val) { // del.val <= cur.val means it is not sorted or equal! del == null means we are done
                del = del.next; // just iterate (inner loop)..
            }
            // when terminated, we are good!:
            // del == null || del.val > cur.val  (is now true!;)
            cur.next = del; // re-link
            cur = del; // iterate (outer loop)...
        } // outer done, cur == null (== "tail")
        return head; // return the original head (with (eventually) less "links"/nodes) ..all "forgotten nodes" are ready for GC
    }
}
```

### Accepted

#### Runtime 0 ms Beats 100%

##### Memory 42.7 MB Beats 7.62%

Comment: It seems like you didnt read the question. Your answer doesnt answer it.

Comment: i read, @matt, but since "a person" (which it works for) was not available..., i thought solving *the (well described & free testable) task* (well, with comments) could help